# text field with submit to email button where the user remains anonymous

Tags: html, text, submit, field, anonymous

I need a large text field with a button that submits the data to an email, ANONYMOUSLY.

Is this possible? is there anything even relatively close?

The code needed is for Tumblr, they have a submit function but requires user data, they have an anonymous ask function but limits input such as links and # of character restrictions. Please help, thank you!

*Update: I found the "Frame Source" for the submit function, is there anyway to edit this so that it takes away the requirement of user data and still manages to work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--[if lte IE 9]><html class="lte_ie9"><![endif]--><!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html><!--<![endif]--><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off"/><title>dirtylittlesecret.me: Submit</title><link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://secure.assets.tumblr.com/images/favicons/favicon.ico?1" /><link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://secure.assets.tumblr.com/assets/styles/submit.css?_v=661435445e73a7e0e806d8a88aa6eb13"><script>
        var Tumblr = Tumblr || {};
        Tumblr.ORIGIN = 'dirtylittlesecretdotme.tumblr.com';
        Tumblr.BASE_HREF = '/submit_form/' + Tumblr.ORIGIN;
    </script><script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://secure.assets.tumblr.com/client/prod/scripts/vendor/index.js?_v=cea000123bea9e149be46553352d3dd2"></script><script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://secure.assets.tumblr.com/assets/scripts/polyfills.js?_v=549a09cd43ef7cda8c7377877e8272c9"></script><script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://secure.assets.tumblr.com/assets/scripts/tumblelog_submission_form.js?_v=476a4d11f679fd793410141f607d7018"></script><script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://secure.assets.tumblr.com/assets/scripts/tumblr_editor.js?_v=cd45d104e85a7abe8a3564ff20254c5a"></script><script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://secure.assets.tumblr.com/assets/scripts/polyfills/placeholders.js?_v=ed246692ceb516394ea75d37e1741d21"></script><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
    src="https://secure.assets.tumblr.com/languages/strings/en_US.js?1342"></script><script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://secure.assets.tumblr.com/assets/scripts/vendor/tiny_mce_3_5_10/tiny_mce.js?_v=e4a6d5f57304ba15e6f1a4a26124baf0"></script><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/submit_form_js/z55SQeV4EwzOvKEJuJjP9sgns/1406072095/submit.js"></script></head><body onload="if (window.jk == undefined) { document.getElementById('container').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('error_no_jk').style.display = 'block'; }"><div id="error_no_javascript"><div class="copy_container"><div class="copy_inner_container"><div class="header">Sorry!</div><div class="copy"><a href="https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&amp;answer=12654">Javascript</a> is required to use this feature.</div></div></div></div><div id="error_no_jk" style="display:none;"><div class="copy_container"><div class="copy_inner_container"><div class="header">Error</div><div class="copy">Sorry, we seem to be having technical trouble. Please try again later.</div></div></div></div><noscript><style type="text/css">
                .l-container { display: none; }
                #error_no_javascript { display: block; }
            </style></noscript><div class="l-container"><form action="/submit_form/dirtylittlesecretdotme.tumblr.com/regular"
            enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="regular_post"><div class="header clearfix"><div id="post_select" class="multi"><span class="txt">Text</span><div id="post_options"><div class="popover popover_menu"><div class="popover_inner"><ul><li><div class="option selected"
                                                        data-option-value="text">Text</div></li><li><div class="option "
                                                        data-option-value="photo">Photo</div></li><li><div class="option "
                                                        data-option-value="link">Link</div></li><li><div class="option "
                                                        data-option-value="quote">Quote</div></li><li><div class="option "
                                                        data-option-value="video">Video</div></li></ul></div></div></div></div><div class="user_info"><span class="tumblelog_name">dirtylittlesecretdotme</span><img src="https://secure.assets.tumblr.com/images/default_avatar/octahedron_closed_48.png" alt="" class="avatar"></div></div><div id="form_container"><input type="hidden" name="post_type" id="post_type" value="regular"><input type="hidden" name="editor_type" id="post_editor_type" value="rich"><input type="hidden" id="post_one_is_rich_text" name="is_rich_text[one]" value="0"><input type="hidden" id="post_two_is_rich_text" name="is_rich_text[two]" value="0"><input type="hidden" id="post_three_is_rich_text" name="is_rich_text[three]" value="0"><div id="comment_form"><div>Leave a comment</div><label for="comment_name">Name</label><input type="text" id="comment_name" name="comment_name"/><label for="comment_url">URL</label><input type="text" id="comment_url" name="comment_url"/><label for="comment_body">Comment</label><textarea id="comment_body" name="comment_body"></textarea><input type="submit" value="Submit comment"/></div><script type="text/javascript">
                        var xi = 'inp';
                        document.write(
                            '<' + xi + 'ut type="hidden" name="jk" value="' + jk() + '"/>' +
                            '<' + xi + 'ut type="hidden" name="jkt" value="7ir10t9pMTQwNjA3MjA5NQ"/>'
                        );
                    </script><div class="input_wrapper"><input class="borderless full optional title" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="off" id="post_one" name="post[one]" type="text" value=""/><label class="optional" for="post_one">Optional</label></div><div class="textarea_wrapper"><textarea class="borderless full no_resize" autofocus="true" id="post_two" name="post[two]"></textarea></div></div><div class="footer clearfix"><div class="confirm_tos_wrapper"><input type="checkbox" name="confirm_tos" id="confirm_tos"><label class="confirm_tos" for="confirm_tos">I accept the <a href="http://dirtylittlesecretdotme.tumblr.com/terms_of_submission" target="_blank">Terms of Submission</a></label></div><button type="submit" id="submit_button" class="chrome blue">Submit</button></div></form><ul id="errors" style="display: none"></ul></div><script>
        var __ = (function() {

            var translation = {
                "You must accept the Terms of Submission.": 'You must accept the Terms of Submission.',
                "Post cannot be empty.":  'Post cannot be empty.',
                "Please select an image file to upload.": 'Please select an image file to upload.',
                "Please enter your name.": 'Please enter your name.',
                "You must enter a valid email address.": 'You must enter a valid email address.'                };

            return function(string) {
                return translation[string] || string;
            };

        })();
    </script><div data-token="post-plexi" class="plexi"></div><script id="tinymce_image_popover" type="text/template"><div class="popover popover_gradient popover_form popover_link"><div class="popover_inner"><form id="insert_image_form"><div class="input_group_wrapper"><input class="image_src" name="src" type="text" placeholder="Image URL" /><input class="image_alt" name="alt" type="text" placeholder="Description (optional)" /></div><button type="submit" class="chrome" data-updatelabel="Update">Insert</button></form></div></div></script><script id="tinymce_link_popover" type="text/template"><div class="popover popover_gradient popover_form popover_link"><div class="popover_inner"><form id="link_form"><div class="input_group_wrapper"><input class="link_url" name="url" type="text" placeholder="Link URL" /><input class="link_title" name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title (optional)" /></div><label class="checkbox_label"><input class="link_target" name="target" type="checkbox" value="" /> Open link in a new window</label><button type="submit" class="chrome" data-updatelabel="Update link">Insert link</button></form></div></div></script><script id="tinymce_source_editor" type="text/template"><div id="source_editor" data-ace="https://secure.assets.tumblr.com/assets/scripts/vendor/ace-noconflict/ace-combined.js?_v=40e256c750c963d9eeaa6ad9103228e8"><div data-token="source-editor-plexi" class="plexi active show"></div><div id="ace_source_editor"></div></div></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using strictly HTML, as your question is tagged, the answer is no. You cannot. If you are trying to go about doing this using a different method, I suggest you tag your question accordingly as currently, with the tags you have and the way your question is written, the answer is no.